# Excel Online - pushing a 2D array not working properly

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript

I have an object that I iterate through. It has two levels so I do two Object.entries iterations.

The end result I need is a 2D array like : [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] but somehow I always get [1,2,3,1,2,3]. I need the first type of array due to a setValues() operation later on to write the data on an Excel.

Here is the code with one iteration through the object, and inside a second iteration where I say : if answer doesn't exist, push a blank space because the array needs a certain length (due to headers).

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {
        
        answerID.push([value["id"],value["created_at"],value["form_id"],value["updated_at"]])
        
        for (const [subKey,subValue] of Object.entries(value["answers"])){
          
          
            if (subValue.hasOwnProperty("answer")) {
                answerDetail.push(subValue["answer"]);
            }
            else{
              answerDetail.push("");
            } 
          
            
      
        }
       
        answerArray.push(answerDetail) 
        // I also tried answerArray.push([answerDetail]) but then it returns [[[1,2,3,1,2,3]]]
        
    }
```

EDIT : by request, I write the structure of result although being full of private data, I can only write a edited version of it. I used JSON formatter to check if my edit is still coherent.

[{"id":"50993654","form_id":"212597363","ip":"","created_at":"2021-10-13 08:15:47","status":"ACTIVE","new":"1","flag":"0","notes":"","updated_at":null,"answers":{"1":{"name":"partie1","order":"2","text":"Partie 1 - QCM - Vous avez une 45 minutes pour soumettre le questionnaire.","type":"control_head"},"3":{"cfname":"Compte à rebours global","name":"saisissezUne","order":"5","selectedField":"","static":"No","text":"","type":"control_widget"},"4":{"name":"email4","order":"3","text":"E-mail","type":"control_email","answer":""},"7":{"name":"prenomprenom","order":"4","text":"Prénom/Prénom","type":"control_textbox","answer":""}}},{"id":"5099284185","form_id":"212592657363","ip":"","created_at":"2021-10-13 07:17:54","status":"ACTIVE","new":"1","flag":"0","notes":"","updated_at":null,"answers":{"1":{"name":"partie1","order":"2","text":"Partie 1 - QCM - Vous avez une 45 minutes pour soumettre le questionnaire.","type":"control_head"},"3":{"cfname":"Compte à rebours global","name":"saisissezUne","order":"5","selectedField":"","static":"No","text":"","type":"control_widget"},"4":{"name":"email4","order":"3","text":"E-mail","type":"control_email","answer":""},"7":{"name":"prenomprenom","order":"4","text":"Prénom/Prénom","type":"control_textbox","answer":""}}}]

Thank if you can help me with this,

Cedric

Comment: What is the value of `result`?

Comment: I've edited my main question with an edited sample of the Object result... thank you !

Comment: @Cedric is this ok `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]` or it was meant to be `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` , and what exactly are those numbers ? which keys ?

Comment: Yes sorry, that was just an structure to explain myself without posting all my Object (which had private data). But you're right, I meant : [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]. Now that I've shown my result Object, I can tell it would mean: [[answer1_FirstElement, answer1_SecondElement , answer1_ThirdElement],[answer2_FirstElement , answer2_SecondElement , answer2_ThirdElement]]. I hope I make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.map` function to change each row by targeting only the `answers` key, then use `Object.values` to retrieve an array of `answers`'s contents and re`map` that with the `name` key.

```js
let str = [{
    "id": "50993654",
    "form_id": "212597363",
    "ip": "",
    "created_at": "2021-10-13 08:15:47",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "new": "1",
    "flag": "0",
    "notes": "",
    "updated_at": null,
    "answers": {
      "1": {
        "name": "partie1",
        "order": "2",
        "text": "Partie 1 - QCM - Vous avez une 45 minutes pour soumettre le questionnaire.",
        "type": "control_head"
      },
      "3": {
        "cfname": "Compte à rebours global",
        "name": "saisissezUne",
        "order": "5",
        "selectedField": "",
        "static": "No",
        "text": "",
        "type": "control_widget"
      },
      "4": {
        "name": "email4",
        "order": "3",
        "text": "E-mail",
        "type": "control_email",
        "answer": ""
      },
      "7": {
        "name": "prenomprenom",
        "order": "4",
        "text": "Prénom/Prénom",
        "type": "control_textbox",
        "answer": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5099284185",
    "form_id": "212592657363",
    "ip": "",
    "created_at": "2021-10-13 07:17:54",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "new": "1",
    "flag": "0",
    "notes": "",
    "updated_at": null,
    "answers": {
      "1": {
        "name": "partie1",
        "order": "2",
        "text": "Partie 1 - QCM - Vous avez une 45 minutes pour soumettre le questionnaire.",
        "type": "control_head"
      },
      "3": {
        "cfname": "Compte à rebours global",
        "name": "saisissezUne",
        "order": "5",
        "selectedField": "",
        "static": "No",
        "text": "",
        "type": "control_widget"
      },
      "4": {
        "name": "email4",
        "order": "3",
        "text": "E-mail",
        "type": "control_email",
        "answer": ""
      },
      "7": {
        "name": "prenomprenom",
        "order": "4",
        "text": "Prénom/Prénom",
        "type": "control_textbox",
        "answer": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

let r = str.map(i => Object.values(i.answers).map(ii => ii.name))

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Thank you for the method, I though map was possible but couldn't figure how, this will be very helpful !